# Finding probabilities based on Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

A group of teachers are required to prepare 4 questions each for a weekly quiz. The number of questions made in a week has a Poisson distribution with a mean of 6.

1. Find the probability that the group manages to write enough questions for the upcoming weekly quiz.

**My understanding:**

Let X be denoted as the number of questions in a week.

Poisson distribution with $\lambda = 6$: $X \sim Po(6)$

We are to find $P(X \geq 4)$ which is $0.848796117223352$ (calculated).

2. As some teachers in the group are busy with other responsibilities, there is a probability of 40% that only half of the group will work on the quiz questions. If only half of the group work on the questions then only 3 questions are prepared on average. If the group fails to finish 4 questions that week, what is the probability that only half the group worked on the questions?

**My understanding:**

I know that we are to find $P(50\%\text{ of team})$ if $X < 4$ but I'm not sure how to incorporate the probability of 40%. Perhaps my understanding is incomplete.

3. The principal decides to increase the number of questions in the weekly quiz and asks the group of teachers to use every question created. If a student has a probability of 40% in answering the questions correctly and is expected to answer 2 questions correctly in the upcoming quiz, what is the probability that the group of teachers worked on creating the questions that week?

As you can see, I was only only able to answer question 1 and would need some help in the remainder 2 questions. This is a new topic to me and any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2)
Let $A$ is a random variable denote that only half of the group will work on the quiz questions.
So we know that P(A) = 0.4, and A is bernoulli distribution with parameter p=0.4.
And we also know that given A, the conditional distribution $X|A$ is poisson(3).

The problem is "given $X<4$, the probability that $A$ is true". So we want to find out $P(A|X<4)$. By the Bayesian theorem:
$P(A|X<4)=\frac{P(A,X<4)}{P(X<4)}=\frac{P(X<4|A)P(A)}{P(X<4)}=\frac{P(X<4|A)P(A)}{P(X<4|A)+P(X<4|A^c)}$
where $A^c$ is "more than half of the group will work on the quiz questions".
We have already known $P(X<4|A)$ because $X|A$ is Poi(3). $P(A)$ is 0.4 because of bernoulli, and $P(X<4|A^c)$ is Poi(6). So now you can find the probability of $P(A|X<4)$.

(3)
I'm not sure if I understand this question well...
A student has probability 0.4 in answering the questions correctly and is expected to answer 2 questions correctly. We can assume that the number of answering questions correctly is Binomial(n, p=0.4), so the expected correctly answer $\mu=np=0.4n=2$, so $n=5$.
Thus the question become to "given that the number of questions is 5, find the probability of $A^c$", that is $P(A^c|X=5)$.
Again using Bayesian theorem:
$P(A^c|X=5)=\frac{P(X=5|A^c)P(A^c)}{P(X=5)}=\frac{P(X=5|A^c)P(A^c)}{P(X=5|A^c)+P(X=5|A)}$
We have already known $X|A^c$ is Poi(6), $X|A$ is Poi(3), so the probability can be easily computed.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your explanation. However, correct me if I'm wrong, is the last formula missing something? Should it be $\frac{P(X = 5|A^c)P(A^c)}{P(X = 5|A^c)+P(X = 5|A)}$?

Comment: @Moonshine45 Yes you're right, I missed this term. I've corrected the content, thanks!